# How to select MySQL view in datatable in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I create a database view from one of my table in MySQL I need help on how to render the table in ignited datatable. Any help will be appreciated. 
I have tried selecting it as normal table e.g

```
$this->datatables->select();
$this->datatables->..............
```

But the data returned is empty.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have successfully created a view named `myView` then try this

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM myView');
```

`$query` is an object that is used to [generate results](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html). 
In this example `$data` will be an array of objects.

```
$data = $query->result();
```

CodeIgniter has several different "result" types. See the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) for details.

Comment: But it returned an empty data.

Comment: @BabatundeMisbah - see my revised answer.